# Convert mm-dd-yyyy to yyyy-mm-dd

Tags: java, android, sqlite

When I grab the current date, I pull the month, day and year, use a string builder and end up with a mm-dd-yyyy format that I put into a textview. When I save data to an sqlitedb, I just grab the date from the textview and insert it. This doesn't work well for date functions as they require yyyy-mm-dd format.

What's the best way to handle this?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Use two [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) instances.

```
String dateString1 = "16-04-2011";
Date date = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy").parse(dateString1);
String dateString2 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").format(date);
System.out.println(dateString2); // 2011-04-16
// ...
```

But better is to just use [`java.util.Date`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Date.html) all the time to hold the value and apply formatting on the front end only. JDBC offers the [`PreparedStatement#setDate()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#setDate%28int,%20java.sql.Date%29) to set a [`java.sql.Date`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Date.html) in a SQL string.

```
preparedStatement.setDate(1, new java.sql.Date(date.getTime()));
```

From the other side, to get it from the DB, just use [`ResultSet#getDate()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#getDate%28java.lang.String%29) and upcast it to `java.util.Date`.

```
Date date = resultSet.getDate("columnname");
```

Comment: +1 for getting the date from the database as a Date object.  Then you can format the date as needed in each particular view.

Answer (score 0):

Another Approach you could take:

```
/**
 * This Method Takes an Input String in the format of MM/dd/yyyy
 * and converts it to yyyy-MM-dd
 *
 * @param originalString
 * @return
 */
private String convertMMddyyyyToyyyyMMdd(String originalString) {
    StringBuilder dateBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    dateBuilder = dateBuilder.append(originalString.substring(6)).append("-").append(originalString.substring(0, 2)).append("-").append(originalString.substring(3, 5));
    return dateBuilder.toString();
}
```